# VBA macro to extract information from MSP to MSE

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I'm trying to create a macro that runs every time I open a specific MS Excel file and that retrieves information from my MS Project file.

In my MS Excel file, I store the status of documentation, see below:

[MS Excel structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6ghQ.png)

In my MS Project file, I keep track of the status of documentation, see below:

[MS Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp6Mq.png)

*Note: I created the Doc ID and Doc Status in MS Project as 'Custom Fields'.*

The goal of the macro is, therefore, to update the Excel with the latest documentation status shown in MS Project, without the need of doing it manually (the number of documents is extensive, images above are only an example)

I have no experience with VBA, I just know that it can be very ***powerful***, so I want to make use of it and learn little by little.

I tried looking in internet for a macro that does what I'm looking after, but I can't find an exact example of it. Also, since I lack experience with VBA I cannot derive a solution from other (different) examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic framework to get status from Project into Excel.

```
Sub GetStatusFromProject()

    ' get reference to Project application and remember if it was already open
    Dim projWasClosed As Boolean
    Dim prjApp As MSProject.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set prjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
    If prjApp Is Nothing Then
        Set prjApp = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
        projWasClosed = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' open project file & get reference to custom status field
    prjApp.FileOpenEx Name:="<full path & filename>", ReadOnly:=True
    Dim fldStatus As Long
    fldStatus = prjApp.FieldNameToFieldConstant("Doc Status")
    
    Dim wst As Worksheet
    Set wst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Document Status")
    
    ' loop through list of document IDs in Excel (Doc IDs in column B, starting at row 2)
    Dim r As Long
    r = 2
    Dim docID As String
    docID = wst.Cells(r, 2)
    Do While Len(docID) > 0
        If prjApp.Find("Doc ID", "equals", docID) Then
            wst.Cells(r, 3) = prjApp.ActiveCell.Task.GetField(fldStatus)
        Else
            wst.Cells(r, 3) = "doc ID not found"
        End If
        r = r + 1
        docID = wst.Cells(r, 2)
    Loop
    
    ' close the project file and optionally close the application
    prjApp.FileCloseEx pjDoNotSave
    If projWasClosed Then
        prjApp.Quit pjDoNotSave
    End If

End Sub
```

Note: this code uses early binding, so set a reference to the Microsoft Project Object Library (in the VB editor, Tools:References, scroll through the list and check the box for this library).

Comment: Incredible! Awesome! I'm speechless! Thank you very much Rachel!! :)